# When mouse scroll down, scroll some div up

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I would like to know how to make when the mouse scroll down a div on top of the website start to climb (scroll up) into the browser window.

Do like the logo (the center arrow logo) on [this site](http://youssef-habchi.com/)

Comment: show us what you have tried

Answer (score -1):

You can use javascript to check the scroll ratio. Send an AJAX request on the listener and see if the user has scrolled enough to hide that div.

Comment: ajax has nothing to do here